# SQL Server 2008 R2 - select hierarchical data

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server which holds categories and sub-categories. They are connected by a relation between `ID` and `PID`.

Top level items have a `PID` of 0 and other rows have the `PID` of their parents.

What would be the most efficient way to get this data?

The naive algorithm for this would be to loop through the list of parents and then get the children for each parent in a different query (either against the DB or the dataset).

Is there any methods built in to the framework to support a better way of doing this? Something that will allow me to easily bind to a repeater (or other data control).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming at least SQL Server 2005 I'd use a single query against a [recursive common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, updated the title with the version of SQL Server. I'll check out the link. Thank you!

Comment: Can you also please point me to a good resource on using the result in C#? What is the recommended control / method for displaying the data? Is there an existing control which allows for a simple bind?\

Comment: My C# is somewhat rusty but you would just bind it to a repeater the same as any other query result.

Comment: I'm not sure a repeater would automatically know how to display this data (in some type of hierarchy), that is part of what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I needed t get me moving along.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Comman Table Expression` to get the hierarchical data in Sql Server.